getting trimmed mean with no categorization in big query
I have a query result named 'uniqueClientsWithLifeTime' that includes a clientid and their average lifetime in months, no categories
Iḿ trying to get the trimmed mean (removing outliers) for the lifetime column
this is my query so far
#upper bound and lower bound
WITH
bounds AS (
  SELECT
    PERCENTILE_CONT(ClientLifeTime, .25) OVER() AS lower_bound,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(ClientLifeTime, .75) OVER() AS upper_bound
  FROM 
    uniqueClientsWithLifeTime
)

SELECT
  AVG(ClientLifeTime) as trimmed_mean,
FROM 
  uniqueClientsWithLifeTime
WHERE 
  ClientLifeTime > (SELECT bounds.lower_bound FROM bounds)
  AND 
  ClientLifeTime < (SELECT bounds.upper_bound FROM bounds) 

but I get an error that says:
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
and
If I do SELECT bounds.lower_bound FROM bounds or the upper_bound, I do get a value although Iḿ not sure if it is the correct value.
Things I've looked into:

I check this article on how to do this but it seems to provide a solution to if you have data that can be splitted on categories although Iḿ not sure how to implement the function there in BigQuery
https://tech.aaronteoh.com/bigquery-parameter-estimation/#trimmed_mean

thereś also another function called approx_quantiles which seems to be a more recent approach on how to get percentiles, but Iḿ not sure how to implement it
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approx_quantiles


Any help is appreciated

I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with the SQL ... you have a good puzzle here.  Do you have some sample de-identified data that you can share that illustrates the puzzle?  I'd love to have a go myself and see it happen.

I just had a notion ... parenthesis ... when you have an expression
X < (expr)
Then the parenthesis is used to declare the order of execution as in
X < (1+2)3  instead of X < 1+23
You are using parenthesis on a SELECT which is a "special" mechanism to produce a scalar result.
Try the following:
ClientLifeTime > ((SELECT lower_bound FROM bounds))
Lets's see what happens

The problem with current solution is that windowing function is not the same as aggregate function - former is not reducing ("aggregating") number of rows, while the latter does.
Windowing function might serve same purpose, but it won't change number of rows at all...
It's pretty fundamental concept for sql-based platforms, so I'd really recommend to go back to the basics on this one:
https://www.google.com/search?q=window+functions+and+aggregate+functions
Solution-wise your second idea is the right one:
#upper bound and lower bound
WITH
bounds AS (
  SELECT
    APPROX_QUANTILES(ClientLifeTime, 100)[OFFSET(25)] AS lower_bound,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(ClientLifeTime, 100)[OFFSET(75)] AS upper_bound
  FROM 
    uniqueClientsWithLifeTime
)

SELECT
  AVG(ClientLifeTime) as trimmed_mean,
FROM 
  uniqueClientsWithLifeTime
WHERE 
  ClientLifeTime > (SELECT bounds.lower_bound FROM bounds)
  AND 
  ClientLifeTime < (SELECT bounds.upper_bound FROM bounds) 

100 will translate quantiles into percentile (for 100 quantiles 1 quantile = 1 percentile).
more details about the function you can find here.

@Georgina_Skibinski you made my day and I learned something new.. cheers and thank you.
